# Reload a jsp page from servlet when form data is involved

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect

I have a jsp that calls a servlet. This servlet does some tasks and then I want to return to the page I was just at and reload it. This would be simple if I knew the exact url it would be each time using the redirectUrl. However, I can't hard code a value in this as it is dynamically created. Is there a way to do this when the previous url is Not known to me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, do you need move from jsp to servlet, and return to the same jsp? If this is what you need, I would put some hidden input in jsp form with path

```
<input type="hidden" name="jspPath" value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}"/>
```

So full solution is below:

page1.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
${requestScope.dataFromServlet }
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/HelloWorldServlet " method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="jspPath" value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldServlet.java

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jspPath = request.getParameter("jspPath");
        if(jspPath == null || "".equals(jspPath))
            jspPath = "errorPage.jsp";

        request.setAttribute("dataFromServlet", "Hello World");

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(jspPath);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```